# Trying to create custom toolbar in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I want to create my own **Toolbar** which would be an extension of **Ext.toolbar.Toolbar**.

I define my StandardToolbar class like this :

```
Ext.define('js.grid.StandardToolbar', {

    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',

    initComponent : function () {


        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'tbfill'
            }]
    },
```

And then when I create my Grid, I pass it in like so :

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('js.grid.myGrid', {
    tbar: Ext.create('js.grid.StandardToolbar')
});
```

However Extjs trips over this.

My error stack is this :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   ext-all-debug.js:38282Ext.define.getRefItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:38282Base.implement.callParent
>   ext-all-debug.js:4263Ext.define.getRefItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:49999getItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:21998cq.Query.Ext.extend.execute
>   ext-all-debug.js:22210Ext.apply.query
>   ext-all-debug.js:22337Ext.define.getDockedItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:44420Ext.define.getDockingRefItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:44430Ext.define.getRefItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:51780getItems
>   ext-all-debug.js:21998cq.Query.Ext.extend.execute
>   ext-all-debug.js:22213Ext.apply.query
>   ext-all-debug.js:22337Ext.define.query
>   ext-all-debug.js:37146Ext.define.getScrollTarget ext-all-

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It was the old *forgotToCallParentInInitComponent* problem. I just added the line **this.callParent();** after I add items.

```
Ext.define('js.grid.StandardToolbar', {

    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',

    initComponent : function () {


        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'tbfill'
            }]
        this.callParent();
    },
```